# "Factory reset" for D40?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d40, body

I'm getting my D40 prepped to be sold, and I want to set the camera back to the original factory settings.  When I do the "two button" reset (holding the "I" and "info" buttons down for two seconds), the camera restarts, but does not reset my settings.  When I choose the menu option to do so (Menu->Custom Settings->Reset), this also does not reset my settings.

In either case, the camera still has my image comment; still has my optimization settings within the shooting menu, etc.

Is there a more aggressive "factory" reset that can be performed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual for `D40` the two-button reset does not affect custom settings (p38).

The `Custom Settings Menu` has another `Reset` option to clear them (p74).

pp113-114 describe default settings and what gets reset with various reset controls.

<sup>There is also a tiny low-level reset switch next to the USB port (p108) --
to be used when the camera completely stalls (freezes).</sup>

Comment: There isn't a true "Factory Reset" available, but the resets described in the manual get you almost all the way there.  If someone has set something and can't remember what was done, and is now taking strange photos, the resets you described should do the trick.  I ended up deleting the image comment information by hand.